# Regex matching dynamic words within an html string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an html string to work with as follows:

```
string html = new MvcHtmlString(item.html.ToString()).ToHtmlString();
```

There are two different types of text I need to match although very similar.  I need the initial `^^` removed and the closing `|^^` removed.  Then if there are multiple clients I need the `^` separating clients changed to a comma(,).

```
^^Client One- This text is pretty meaningless for this task, but it will exist in the real document.|^^

^^Client One^Client Two^Client Three- This text is pretty meaningless for this task, but it will exist in the real document.|^^
```

I need to be able to match each client and make it bold.

**Client One**- This text is pretty meaningless for this task, but it will exist in the real document.

**Client One**, **Client Two**, **Client Three**- This text is pretty meaningless for this task, but it will exist in the real document.

A nice stack over flow user provided the following but I could not get it to work or find any matches when I tested it on an online regex tester.

```
const string pattern = @"\^\^(?<clients>[^-]+)(?<text>-.*)\|\^\^";

    var result = Regex.Replace(html, pattern,
                                m =>
                                {
                                    var clientlist = m.Groups["clients"].Value;
                                    var newClients = string.Join(",", clientlist.Split('^').Select(s => string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", s)));

                                    return newClients + m.Groups["text"];
                                });
```

I am very new to regex so any help is appreciated.

Comment: As much as I want to help here, it's almost impossible to give an answer that won't devolve into teaching you Regex. So yeah, first learn Regex because it's just that useful/important. In the interim though, your problem above should be easy enough that you can do it using just using some fancy `String.Replace` + logic. But yeah, take the time to lean Regex.

Comment: One other thing, groups in c# I'm pretty sure use quotes instead of `<` and `>`. So `(?<clients[^-]+)` should actually read `(?'clients'[^-]+`).

Comment: Well that did help me to get a bit farther, it is now matching in RegEx Buddy.  But the above code is still not bolding the clients.. `const string pattern = @"\^\^(?'client'[^-]+)(?'text'-.*)|\^\^";` @sircodesalot

Comment: @sircodesalot: I think you must be thinking of some other language with respect to the group construct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression. For calrity and in case of link rot both are acceptable syntax.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks for the documentation, it looks like (per the documentation) both `<>` and `''` work (compare the patterns in rows two and three). I've always used quotes, but it's useful to know that there are other options as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to C# so forgive me if I make rookie mistakes :)

```
const string pattern = @"\^\^([^-]+)(-[^|]+)\|\^\^";

var temp = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, "<strong>$1</strong>$2");
var result = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\^", "</strong>, <strong>");
```

I'm using `$1` even though MSDN is vague about using that syntax to reference subgroups.

Edit: if it's possible that the text after `-` contains a `^` you can do this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\^(?=.*-)", "</strong>, <strong>");
```

Comment: The double escaping was throwing it off.  As soon as I removed the double escaping it seems to work just like I need it to.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You are a genius by the way. :)

Comment: Ah so the double escaping is not necessary in C#, neat. I'll remove it for future readers. And thank you :)

Comment: @funkwurm: if you weren't using the `@""` syntax you would have needed the double escaping. The `@` form of quoting strings means that `\` is no longer a special character and doesn't need escaping.